# Swift: app runs well in simulator but crashes on actual iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner and I created a kind of tic tac toe game and have been running it on the iPhone 5s simulator to weed out issues and just now I tried it out on my actual iPhone 5s and the app crashes when the AI is supposed to take its turn. Xcode draws an error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on the line below:

```
//Bunch of functions that check for exact spots:

func checktop(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("top", checkFor(value, spots: [1,2,3])) //This line has error
}
func checkbottom(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("bottom", checkFor(value, spots: [7,8,9]))
}
func checkmidAcross(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("middle across", checkFor(value, spots: [4,5,6]))
}
func checkleft(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("left down", checkFor(value, spots: [1,4,7]))
}
func checkmidDown(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("middle down", checkFor(value, spots: [2,5,8]))
}
func checkright(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("right down", checkFor(value, spots: [3,6,9]))
}
func checkLRdiag(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("left-right diagonal", checkFor(value, spots: [1,5,9]))
}
func checkRLdiag(value:Int)->(location:String,pattern:String) {
    return ("right-left diagonal", checkFor(value, spots: [3,5,7]))
}
```

Why would the app run just fine on the simulator but crash on the actual device? What's going wrong?
Here is my checkFor method:

```
func checkFor(value:Int, spots:Int[])->(String) {
    var conclusion = ""
    for cell in spots {
        if plays[cell] == value {
            conclusion += "1"
        }
        else {
            conclusion += "0"
        }
    }
    return conclusion
}

func isOccupied(spot:Int)->(Bool) {
    return Bool(plays[spot])
}
```

Comment: You are accessing freed up memory. `value` might be `nil`.

Comment: @duci9y so if my `value` is `nil` how can I fix my code? Should I just take out all the `value`s?

Comment: Because that would then screw up the rest of my code

Answer (score 0):

My App crashed with the same error on my device but not on the simulator. It turns out that my iOS 8 beta version did not match my Xcode beta version. So I would check and make sure that your iOS 8 beta and Xcode beta are both on version 4 (the latest at the time of this writing). Also make sure that you completely reinstall the App, clean build folder etc.

This is of course assuming there is not an error with your code. Maybe you can post your checkFor method if the above does not work.

Comment: So my phone isn't on iOS 8 beta so I just set my app's deployment target at 7.1 and I'm fairly sure that is what my phone is, I don't think that should be a problem? And ok, I just posted my checkFor method.

Comment: So the App runs fine on iOS 8 Simulator but not on your non-iOS 8 device, correct? And you have the latest beta of Xcode 6 correct? If that is the case then it could just be a bug that you need to wait for Apple to fix. However, the fact that you are receiving BAD_ACCESS on that line makes me think, as others have pointed out, that your "value" is nil. You should debug that and see if your value is indeed nil. If it is, then you have an error in your code somewhere. Maybe from using an optional type. But the fact that it runs fine on iOS 8 simulator makes me think it might be an Apple bug.

Comment: yes, I'm now on the latest version of Xcode 6 so you may be correct however I have a yellow error message now that says, "Relocatable dylibs (e.g. embedded frameworks) are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later". Could that have to do with the problem? @gfrs

Comment: Is Xcode maybe having the problem because I am not running it on an iOS 8 device?

Comment: That embedded frameworks warning is actually a bug in beta 4. You can ignore it. Let me know if running it on you device works now that you have the latest Xcode. Be sure to uninstall the App and clean build folder before running. If you still get the crash, then your final solution is try to find a way to run the App on an actual device running iOS 8. If it still crashes, then the error must be in your code, else it is most likely an Apple bug.

Comment: So far the app is still crashing on the device, what exactly do you mean by cleaning the build folder?

Comment: Alright, so I just tried the app on my iPad, and other than the fact that everything looks weird due to the fact that I didn't load in iPad-sized assets, the app works. It doesn't crash. How can that be possible?

Comment: Is your iPad running iOS 8? Also when I say clean build folder, there is a toolbar button for cleaning the build folder. Just search in the help bar, clean build folder and you should see it come up.

Comment: No, it is running iOS 7 same as my iPhone. And yeah I got that, still didn't work

Comment: So just to recap, your App works on iOS 7.1 simulator [all devices], iOS 8.0 simulator [all devices], iOS 7.1 actual device [iPad] but not on iOS 7.1 actual device [iPhone]. If this is the case, then it is most certainly an internal bug with Xcode 6/Swift. If you search around you can see many people (myself included) with issues  running Xcode 6 Apps on iOS 7.1 devices. Unfortunately the only solution is to just wait it out and hope Apple fixes the issue in the next beta release.